# Powershell variable from HTML table one value

Tags: html, powershell

I'm beginner in power shell ( HTML ) and I need some help. I want to get a variable from the [McAfee website](https://www.mcafee.com/enterprise/en-us/downloads/security-updates.html). In this page there is a table where you can download the latest `.dat` files.

I only need the version number - now it's 8963 - from the first table ( Download V2 Virus Definition Updates (DATs) ) and this result needs to be saved in a variable because I want to compare it with other variable from another script.
Now I'm able to query all of the tables with all of the data:

```
$r = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://www.mcafee.com/enterprise/en-us/downloads/security-updates.html
$r.parsedhtml.getelementsbytagname("TR") |
% { ( $_.children | ?{ $_.tagName -eq "td"} | % innerText ) } 
Write-Host
```

Unfortunately it's too much information for me, because list all of the data which is in a table.

The retrived data in pic.: [data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpcPu.jpg)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It would help alot if you could post an example of how the data looks like.

Comment: I extended my question with picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpcPu.jpg

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this isn't the cleanest method, but if you expect the first entry to allwayse be the one supplying the Filename of the needed .exe you could use this:

```
($r.parsedhtml.getelementsbytagname("TR") |% { ( $_.children | ?{ $_.tagName -eq "td"} | % innerText ) } | Select-Object -First 1).Split('xdat')[0]
```

This basically takes the first String of your query, splits the string on the position of `xdat` and than takes everything before `xdat`.

The Output then is `8963`.

If you want to do it the more correct way, you should look out for the correct html-attribute to filter for.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. This is what I need, because if the mcafee have a newer version I will able to compare with other versions. Yes I will, but I need a fast solution because the other half of the script is waiting for this. Thanks again!